# ¿que interfaz o funciones en javafx debo sobreescribir para hacer mi propio control?

Tags: javafx

Como puede verse aqui he conseguido acceder a la interfaz skin y skinnable ademas de listar el CSS
aplicable al control button;pero...¿existe algun metodo como paint o algo asi ,para sobreescribirlo
y hacer asi mi propio control?
Como mucho he logrado profundizar hasta ButtonBehavior pero parece que la logica de dibujo no esta centralizada en los controles.
La version del java es 8.o fx y esta hecho cont fxml aunque minimamente

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Skinnable;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
        javafx.scene.control.Button ese= (javafx.scene.control.Button)((GridPane)root).getChildren().toArray()[0];
        Skin<?>broton =((javafx.scene.control.Skinnable) ese).getSkin();
        com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin sk1=((com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin)broton);
        System.out.println(sk1.toString());
        java.lang.Object obj1[]=sk1.getCssMetaData().stream().toArray();
        for (Object d1 :obj1) {
            System.out.println(d1.toString());

        }
       java.util.List<javafx.css.CssMetaData<? extends javafx.css.Styleable, ?>>mimetadata=sk1.getCssMetaData();
       System.out.println(mimetadata.size());
       
        };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Ahora el controller:

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
public class Controller {
    //Controller(){};
 @FXML
 Button mioboton;

}
```

ahora el fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="mioboton" text="hola" /;#&gt;
    </children>
</GridPane>
```